# requestMatchers("").permitAll() does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a controller authentication using Spring Boot security.

When customizing my `filterChain` I get 401 Unauthorized for resources I have specifically permitted.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(h2ConsolePath + "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

        http
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin();

        http
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

        http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
```

For example I want to access my h2-console and I don't want any authentication to happen when I access the h2-console. But I still get an error message with the status code 403 Forbidden.

Even when I remove this line `.anyRequest().authenticated();` I get the same error, which makes me think that this whole filter chain doesn't get applied maybe? But when I debug it and set a breakpoint inside the method the program jumps inside the method, so it should get applied?
After many hours of research I'm not sure how to proceed.

**Edit:**

I also added a `TestController` with a `TestResource` and without the `@PreAuthorize` annotation and when I test it in Postman I get this error message:

> Full authentication is required to access this resource

As already mention I have the feeling that the filter chain isn't applied because even when I remove `.anyRequest().authenticated` the same error still occures, so it doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: configuration looks right, you don't have any other configuration class, right ? and maybe add this and retry `.antMatchers(h2ConsolePath + "/**").csrf().disable()`

Comment: I can't add antMatchers, I think it is deprecated and that requestMatchers does more or less the same thing?

Comment: For h2-console, you have to add the servletPath to the matcher, see here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12310#issuecomment-1328990026

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I finally found the solution. I went back to Java version 1.8 and used `antMatchers` instead of `requestMatchers`.

So this is my final code:

```java
  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler)
            .and()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/test/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(h2ConsolePath + "/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    
    http
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());

    http
        .addFilterBefore(authenticationJwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    
    return http.build();
  }
```