# permitAll() not working in Spring Security 6 with Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have set up a custom SecurityFilterChain with JWT authentication and for testing I permitted all the requests on a test route.

Even with disabling the httpBasic and formLogin authentication I still received 401 unauthorised.
So, I excluded the SpringAutoConfiguration class from @SpringBootApplication. Then I received Whitelabel error page.

I am a beginner so please guide me in solving this issue.

I tried many a variations of the httpSecurity but couldn't find a solution.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class AppConfig {
        public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // simple httpSecurity just to check
    //        return http.sessionManagement(s ->
    //                        s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
    //                .authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
    //                            .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
    //                            .anyRequest().authenticated())
    ////                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
    ////                .formLogin(FormLoginConfigurer::disable)
    //                .build();

    // original code which I want to work with.
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    //                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/").permitAll()
    //                    .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/home").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .addFilterBefore(new JwtTokenValidationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .httpBasic(HttpBasicConfigurer::disable)
    ////            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
    ////            .cors(corsConfigurer -> corsConfigurer
    ////                    .configurationSource(request -> {
    ////                        CorsConfiguration cors = new CorsConfiguration();
    ////                        cors.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:3000"));
    ////                        cors.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
    ////                        cors.setAllowCredentials(true);
    ////                        cors.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
    ////                        cors.setExposedHeaders(List.of("Authorization"));
    ////                        cors.setMaxAge(3600L);
    ////                        return cors;
    ////                    }))
              .build();


    //        return http.build();
    }
    


        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
    }
```

I can further provide the JWTUtil and JWTValidation class.

```
    @RestController
    public class HomeController {
        @GetMapping("/home")
        public String homeController() {
            return "Hello from Home";
        }
    }
```

I tried to create a custom SecurityFilterChain and authenticate using JWT.
I have looked for solutions already present on StackOverflow but they were very old. And still couldn't figure out what am I missing.

Comment: Why are you not using the built in jwt features of spring security as stated in the documentation. If you are a beginner, why have you not read the documentation before asking here?

Comment: @Toerktumlare I havn't reached the point of checking JWT. I am stuck even for basic routing configuration. I read and tried to follow the documentation, official example for basic setup, chatgpt, claude and over the internet for any solution. And, then I had to ask here.

Comment: then you should instead be asking about the documentation instead if you dont understand it. handing out JWTs to browsers is dangerous, and writing custom security is bad practice. Your entire filter should be deleted

Comment: I am asking how to configure a simple security filter chain in which I am facing issue following documentation and further tried looking for solution and mistake in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem a year ago. Using antMatchers instead of requestMatchers did it for me.

Comment: isn't antMatcher deprecated and replaced with requestMatchers() now. So authConfigurer (auth) in the lambda doesn't have a method antMatchers()

Comment: Yes, tbh I don't fully understand it either. But I had the same issue a year ago as you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75768437/requestmatchers-permitall-does-not-work. I switched back to Java 1.8 instead of 1.11 I think and just replaced requestMatchers with antMatchers and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to provide a list of paths where you permit all types of requests in the requestMatchers() method:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
    .requestMatchers("/", "/api/auth/**", "/home" ).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated())
```

You can also add @EnableMethodSecurity annotation in your Config class.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Tried this, It still isn't working. It shows the whitelabel error page.

Comment: You can follow up this example (repo) of configuration: https://github.com/ali-bouali/spring-boot-3-jwt-security